# how to multiple 2 mysql strings

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query and would like to know how to multiple 2 tables value. I tries a few things but it did not work.

MySQL query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE_1 SET
TOTAL =". $db->qstr( $re2[0]['PRICE'] )." * $db->qstr( $re2[0]['QTY'] )";
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What about `"INSERT INTO table SET total = ". $val1 * $val2` ?

Answer (score 0):

NVM, Figured it out..

Thanks all..

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE_1 SET
TOTAL =". $db->qstr( $re2[0]['PRICE'] * $re2[0]['QTY'] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE_1 SET
TOTAL =(". $db->qstr( $re2[0]['PRICE'] )."*".$db->qstr( $re2[0]['QTY'] ).")";
```

or,  compute from `PHP` and assign to query.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE_1 SET
TOTAL =". ($db->qstr( $re2[0]['PRICE'] ) * $db->qstr( $re2[0]['QTY'] ));
```

Answer (score 0):

The expected statement would be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE_1 SET TOTAL = " . ( $db->qstr( $re2[0]['PRICE'] ) * $db->qstr( $re2[0]['QTY'] ) );
```

Comment: that did not work as I tried earlier. but I've answered the question. Thanks for your time.